# How to nest more than one jQuery function so variables are accessible though out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(".BtnTime1").click(function() {

  if ($(".BtnTime1").text() == "Green") {
    var timeIn = parseInt("122");
    $(".BtnTime1").text(timeIn);
  } else {
    $(".BtnTime1").text("Green");
  };

  $(".BtnTime2").click(function() {

    if ($(".BtnTime2").text() == "Green") {
      var timeOut = parseInt("3231");
      $(".BtnTime2").text(timeOut);
    } else {
      $(".BtnTime2").text("Green");
    };

    $(".timeDiff").html(timeOut - timeIn);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Time-In Room</td>
      <td>Time-Out Room</td>
      <td>Time Difference</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="BtnTime1 btn-danger btn-block btn-outline-dark">Green</button></td>
      <td><button class="BtnTime2 btn-danger btn-block btn-outline-dark">Green</button></td>
      <td class="timeDiff"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hi, I have some jQuery code with two functions.

The function will call classes either ".BtnTime1" or ".BtnTime2".

When a HTML button is clicked/toggled it will display a numeric value, then it will minus both variables to work out the difference in number between two fields.

The numeric difference will be populated inside HTML element with class ".timeDiff".

The code works however there can be issues with toggling the HTML buttons, I believe this is because the functions are not properly nested, I need the variables to be accessible in one scope.

How can I clean up this code to avoid button toggle issues and that the functions are nested properly?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleaner way is to initialize the variables outside the functions and don't nest the functions. i have make some modifications to have the exact results
One more thing, its better to use ID's instead of class in such case

```js
var timeIn = '';
var timeOut = '';
$(".BtnTime1").click(function() {

  if ($(".BtnTime1").text() == "Green") {
    timeIn = parseInt("122");
    $(".BtnTime1").text(timeIn);
  } else {
    $(".BtnTime1").text("Green");
  };
});



$(".BtnTime2").click(function() {

  $(".timeDiff").html('');
  if ($(".BtnTime2").text() == "Green" && $(".BtnTime1").text() != "Green") {
    timeOut = parseInt("3231");
    $(".BtnTime2").text(timeOut);
    $(".timeDiff").html(timeOut - timeIn);
  } else {
    $(".BtnTime2").text("Green");
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Time-In Room</td>
      <td>Time-Out Room</td>
      <td>Time Difference</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="BtnTime1 btn-danger btn-block btn-outline-dark">Green</button></td>
      <td><button class="BtnTime2 btn-danger btn-block btn-outline-dark">Green</button></td>
      <td class="timeDiff"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Many thanks Shehzad,  this is just what I wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

how about using the html5 data atrributes to store your variables and then just write one function (keep it DRY)

here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/6k4qpy8f/

js

```
$('.timeBtn').click(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Green' ? $(this).attr('data-number') : 'Green')
  $("#timeDiff").html($('#Btn2').text() - $('#Btn1').text());
})
```

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Time In Room</th>
          <th>Time out Room</th>
          <th>Time Difference</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary timeBtn" data-number='122' id="Btn1">Green</button>
          </td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-secondary timeBtn" data-number='3231' id="Btn2">Green</button></td>
          <td id="timeDiff"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Byran! Interesting approach, something I will keep in mind for future.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(a) {

    var timeIn;
    var timeOut;
    $(".BtnTime1").click(function() {

        if ($(".BtnTime1").text() == "Green") {
            timeIn = parseInt("122");
            $(".BtnTime1").text(timeIn);
        } else {
            $(".BtnTime1").text("Green");
        };


    });

    $(".BtnTime2").click(function() {

        if ($(".BtnTime2").text() == "Green") {
            timeOut = parseInt("3231");
            $(".BtnTime2").text(timeOut);
        } else {
            $(".BtnTime2").text("Green");
        };

        $(".timeDiff").html(timeOut - timeIn);

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed" border="1px">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Time-In Room</td>
          <td>Time-Out Room</td>
          <td>Time Difference</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><button class="BtnTime1 btn-danger btn-block btn-outline-dark">Green</button></td>
          <td><button class="BtnTime2 btn-danger btn-block btn-outline-dark">Green</button></td>
          <td class="timeDiff"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```